# How to Get Facebook ID from iFrame php

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, assign

I am trying to extract the facebook id from an iframe in order to update a module which will display on the user's website and link to the fb page.

For example, when I load this iframe:

```
<iframe src=https://graph.facebook.com/zuck></iframe>
```

You can see that Mark Zuckerberg has the id of 4.  I would simply like to pull this value out of the iframe and assign it to a variable via php.  Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using the FB javascript API.

In your head, add a JS block with:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.api("/zuck", function(response){
        alert(response.id);
    });
};​
```

... replace zuck with the wanted username, eg. "/" + *USERNAME*

Async load the FB JS ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>​
```

Since ID is a public field, you don't need any extra user login stuff; you can just make a call.

Please note ... that is MISSING some usual FB stuff:
FB.init - since we don't need to do any user session related stuff.
[div id="fb-root"][/div] - since we aren't showing any stuff from FB; dialogs, etc. (but with square brackets! :-P )

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to do something similar with php `<?php
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/zuck');
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $parsedJson->id; 
?>
`

Answer (score 0):

as i know it is not possible unfortunately .because it is a security concern.
if you want to extract value from an iframe that source is from your own domain it is possible without any problem.but when the source of iframe is a third party url , accessing dom elements inside it is a security problem.